# How to close a drawer popup with a specific button/area outside it in QML?

Tags: layout, popup, qml, qtquick2, drawer

I've created a drawer and I wish to close it by pressing the same button that triggers it. This button is outside the drawer. But QML doesn't seem to allow this as the only closepolicy (drawer property to close) options for Popups are:

- Popup.NoAutoClose (where I have to click and drag the drawer to close it)
- Popup.CloseOnPressOutside (anywhere outside)
- Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent (anywhere outside) (default)
- Popup.CloseOnReleaseOutside Popup.CloseOnReleaseOutsideParent
- Popup.CloseOnEscape (only on escape button) (default)

Also, I don't seem to be able to click any button outside the drawer when it is visible/drawn for some reason. If that wasn't the case, I wouldn't have this issue either.

Can I make the drawer close by clicking on a specific button/area outside it?

Does anyone know the solution to this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawer inherited from Popup so we can take those advantages to control the behavior. By setting the **model: false** and **closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose** it is possible to control the drawer from button actions.

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Drawer {
        id: drawer
        width: 0.4 * window.width
        height: window.height
        closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
        modal: false
    }

    Button {
        text: drawer.visible ? "close" : "open"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            drawer.visible = !drawer.visible
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aah, yes. "modal: false" fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shravan Welcome to stackoverflow community. Please upvote and mark as solved.